# Wordpress,Drupal, Asp.net Membership Provider

Tags: wordpress, drupal, asp.net-membership

I need to synchronize three of them but I have already 18k Asp.Net Members. (Offline synchronization)
So how can I convert  default "Password Hashing" of Wordpress and Drupal to Asp.Net Membership's (SHA1 with Salt) ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can. MD5 and SHA1 are uni-directional algorithms. This is why they are used. They provide security for the user passwords. So you will not be able to revert the hash back to the passwords. Nor can you convert from MD5 to SHA1 directly.

In this scenario I think you are stuck with resetting the Drupal and Wordpress user passwords when you merge. (See edits for alternate solution.)

EDIT: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381448/how-do-i-convert-password-hashing-from-md5-to-sha) had a interesting idea / solution. Write some custom code to generate the SHA1 passwords upon your users first logging in. Collect the SHA1 hashes, and use those during merge. Any users you don't get, force them to do a password reset.