# Converting encryption password from MD5 to SHA-256, does my protocol has a flaw?

Tags: md5, sha256, password-encryption

I'm working on a website (PHP + MySQL) that I've got to upgrade. Passwords are stored in the database in MD5, and I'd like it to be something more secure, like SHA-256.

I've already red [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381448/how-do-i-convert-password-hashing-from-md5-to-sha) about "converting" password hashes, but I got an other idea, and I'd like to know if it brings a security problem or not.

Currently, the passwords are checked in php by hashing (in MD5) the given password and compare it with the hash stored in database, *ie*: `if(md5($password) == $hash)`

Let's assume that I hash all the MD5 hashes in SHA-256. I'd have the sha-256 hash of a md5 hash.

*Side note: I know it's not more secure to rehash a hash, that's not the point of my question*

When a user wants to connect, I'd just have to change the `md5($pass)` in `hash('sha256', md5($password), false)` to make it match the value stored in database (assuming $password is the right one)

It seemed a good idea to me as I don't need to keep track of the md5 hash after conversion, ad this doesn't need me to create any new column in my table. I know that this is not going to give me the SHA-256 hash of the original password stored with md5 hash, but this is not my goal. It's just to change the encryption method. Moreover, brute-forcing it seems inefficient, as it is very unlikely that dictionary would have hashes of words...

**Does this way of doing it is flawed?**

Comment: MD5, SHA256 and other such cryptographic algorithms are **not encryption**, they are one-way functions.

Comment: But I don't want to decrypt stored passwords, this seems unsecure, therefore one way functions are more appropriate, right?

Comment: I guess I was not clear: The point is to use the correct terminology, don't call hashing encryption.

Comment: @zaph I sure will as soon as I've fully tested it. Moreover, I wanted to wait a few days to see if anyone else has an other opinion. But I will ;)

Answer (score 3):

Simple hashing of passwords is insufficient, it is subject to rainbow tables and is to fast.

Instead in PHP use [Safe Password Hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php): `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` or a comparable function such as PBKDF2, Bcrypt or script. These function are more secure because of two additions: a repetition count and a random salt. It's all about raising the work factor the attacker must perform.

After all, the point is to have a secure system. Just making it more inconvenient for an attacker is not the answer, there are hacking programs out there to take advantage of poor password security.

Comment: Can you explain how it is less subject to rainbow tables to store hashes, salt and algorithm instead of just the hash?

Comment: If there is no random key component an attacker can have a pre-computed table of hashes to passwords, a rainbow table. With a random key the attacker would have to have a hash table for each key. Also if there is a random key used with an HMAC the password hash will not be the same for all identical passwords, password_hash() and password_verify() accomplish this transparently. Otherwise if an attacker obtains the password DB and finds one password from the hash all other other user's with the same password are known.

Comment: So it's because there's a randomly generated hash that it's more secure, and that password_hash ensure that there is one. Got it, thanks a lot

Comment: The reason to use password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt or script is because additionally they have a repetition count to make the calculation slower in the area of 100ms or so. It is all about raising the work factor the attacker must perform.

Comment: @Tloz - Just to underline, important is that each password gets its own random salt. And one can calculate about [14 Giga SHA-256 per second](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance), that's what zapf meant with being too fast.